Deming regression and Numerical Recipes
I'm trying to sort through Deming regression, meaning that I want to fit a function (a straight line) through data that have "errors" in both the x and y coordinates. I'm looking at Numerical Recipes, chapter 15.3, and finding the basis for their approach to be mysterious.
Most puzzling to me is the merit function they choose to minimize:
\begin{equation}
\chi^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{(y_{i} - a - b\cdot x_{i})^{2}}{\sigma_{yi}^{2} + b^{2}\cdot\sigma_{xi}^{2}}
\end{equation}
This looks wrong to me. $y_{i} - a - b\cdot x_{i}$ is the residual difference in y. Shouldn't there be a additional term, one for minimizing the squared distance between the line and x data?

+1. It helps to draw a diagram: you should quickly discover that the distance between $(x_i,y_i)$ and the line $y=a+bx$ equals $|y_i-a-bx_i|/\sqrt{1+b^2},$ which begins looking a lot like the terms in this merit function ;-).

@Kjetil Just be aware that the chapter number varies with the edition of NR--and there are many of them.

I want to show how merely by looking at the expression for $\chi^2$ one can determine it is correct.
We need a basic geometric observation about Euclidean spaces.  I am going to derive this in a way that reveals how you can (i) easily remember the formula and (ii) write it down by inspection, without doing any algebra.
In $d$ dimensions, the unit vectors $\mathbf v$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the oriented hyperplanes
$$H_{\mathbf{v}}: \{\mathbf{x}\mid \mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{x} = 0\}.$$
The signed distance between any point $\mathbf x$ in the direction of $\mathbf v$ and $H_{\mathbf v}$ is given by the dot product $\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf x.$ Consequently, when $H_{\mathbf v}$ is translated to an origin $\mathbf a,$ the signed distance is $\mathbf{v} \cdot (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{a}).$
Specializing to two dimensions, $d=2,$ the oriented hyperplanes are directed lines.  Thus, the general equation of a line has the form given above.  Writing out the coordinates with $\mathbf x = (x,y),$ $\mathbf v = (\beta,-\alpha),$ and origin $\mathbf = (0,y_0)$ puts any non-vertical line (that is, $\alpha \ne 0$) in the form
$$0 = \mathbf v\cdot (\mathbf x - \mathbf a) = (\beta,-\alpha) \cdot(x - 0, y - y_0) = \beta x - \alpha(y - y_0).$$
Equivalently,
$$\alpha y =\alpha y_0 +  {\beta}x \tag{*}$$
with $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 1.$

To apply this result, note that the equation of the line as given in the question is
$$(1)y = a + bx.$$
Comparing with $(*)$ shows that up to a multiple, $1\ \propto \ \alpha$ and $b\ \propto \  \beta.$  Since we have required $1 = |\mathbf v| = \sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2},$ we must divide both sides by this quantity, finding
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}},\ \beta = \frac{b}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}.$$
This reveals the distance formula to be of the form
$$\mathbf v \cdot (\mathbf x - \mathbf a) = \frac{b x - y + \text{constant}}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}.$$
Because points on the line are at zero distance from it, evidently $\text{constant}=a.$
Look back over this derivation to fix in your mind how this formula can be written down merely by inspecting the original expression of the line.
The distance between any data point $(x_i,y_i)$ and the line given by $y = a + bx$ therefore is the absolute value of the foregoing quantity,
$$|\mathbf v \cdot (\mathbf x_i - \mathbf a)| = \frac{|y_i - a - b x_i|}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}.\tag{**}$$
That's it for the geometry.  Now for the statistical part of the result.  By definition, a chi-squared value is a squared residual (like the squared distance) divided by its variance: that is, its the square of a standardized residual.  Because this fraction is unitless, it will not change upon rescaling the residual.  Accordingly, we may ignore the denominator in the fraction $(**).$  The squared residual, then, is
$$r_i^2 = |y_i - a - bx_i|^2 = (y_i - a - bx_i)^2$$
and the variance of the residual is
$$\operatorname{Var}(\pm(y_i - a - bx_i)) = (\pm 1)^2\left(\operatorname{Var}(y_i) + (-b)^2\operatorname{Var}{x_i}\right) = \sigma_{y_i}^2 + b^2 \sigma_{x_i}^2.$$
Dividing the first by the second gives
$$\chi^2_i = \frac{(y_i - a - bx_i)^2}{\sigma_{y_i}^2 + b^2 \sigma_{x_i}^2}.$$
Summing over the data shows the sum of squared standardized residuals equals the $\chi^2$ expression in the question, QED.
